# Heatsink temperature probe

Tags: measurement, temperature, heatsink, thermal, probe

I read around that with an anonymous heatsink, you can measure its temperature when at regimen dissipating P watts. Then, (T-Tamb)/P gives its thermal resistance. 
Is that meaningful? Can I do this measurement roughly to stay on the safe side?

I'd like to put the probe in these heatsinks while dissipating a certain amount of watts and see if are close to 5°C/W:

[image]

Comment: Sure that works fine.  Just remember that the heat loss will depend on the orientation and any air flow.

Comment: To stay safe I need to measure the hottest spot, am I right?

Comment: To stay safe, get a heat sink that comes with a datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what an "anonymous heatsink" is, so some general (if obvious) chat follows.

Usually you will know the safe working temperature of the device being cooled and armed with it's data sheet, you ought to be able to select a suitable HS - you give no idea of the application though.

You might want to look at the information given by heat-sink manufacturers to get you started. e.g. 
https://www.aavid.com/sites/default/files/technical/papers/how-to-select-heatsink.pdf  and look at their sites where they may have design guide software or the offer of expert advice e.g. http://www.aavid.com/thermal-design-help
Google is your friend.

When using heat-sink paste, usually less is more! You are not making a cream-filled cake, but filling holes in the surface to increase contact area, and so thermal conductivity. Again, read the product data provided by manufacturers.

You need good contact if adding a probe (thermocouple etc) for it to be effective. You also need to consider at what point you measure temperature. Will it be the heatsink/source interface, the internal structure of the SH, or the outer surface? Centre or edge? Of course whenever we measure anything we effect the outcome! The point being that it will be more difficult to measure the effect of a small HS.

Having said that, it's useful to measure the effectiveness of a HS/temperature of the source during operation, so that the protected part can have it's parameters altered to modulate the amount of heat produced. Heat can drastically effect the lifespan of a device.

Comment: when saying anonymous, I mean that I DO NOT have its datasheet/information :)

Comment: I see! ;) I even googled "anonymous HS" in case I'd missed something :D
Those in the photo look like early 186 or 286 processor heat sinks IIRC. Check the thermal info of an 80186 against your device. If power/noise and over-cooling is not an issue, you could fit a fan to increase the conductivity to air. Many fans were crudly fitted to these HS by forcing a self-tapping screw thread into the gap between the fins. Also note that many devices have thermal shutdown, and in some, the temperature value is presented to the outside world so that temperature modulation can occur.

Comment: To measure the junction, I'd probably drill a snug hole, top to bottom and attach a suitably shaped thermocouple pressed against the device. Insulating the back will reduce losses through the sensor, but also effect the overall system. see my comment above as questions such as "do I sleeve the sensor" then arise. Not an easy one to crack.

Comment: I used to have a similar issue, calibrating the controllers for heater band systems. in that instance, I used an aluminium block with two holes drilled very close to each other containing the feedback sensor and my thermocouple that emulated the real-world use as well as I could. Again, no answer, just bumph that may spur your own thought processes ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you could measure the temperature at the device/heatsink junction, then you would have an accurate answer, yes.  The further you get away from that point, the lower the temperature reading you will get because the heatsink does not have infinite thermal conductivity internally.

The most accurate measurement you'll make is with a tiny thermocouple buried in the surface of the heatsink directly under where the thermal load is mounted, but that's probably more hassle than you want to go to for a $1 heatsink ;)

You could try putting two big ceramic-case/wirewound resistors on the bottom with a 5mm gap between them, and then the temperature-sensor of your choice (e.g. DS18b20, LM335, etc) between the resistors.  By putting the sensor between the resistors, it will be at pretty much the same temperature as the heatsink/resistor interface.

Comment: But this is for measuring the thermal resistance of the junction-heatsink. My question is related to measuing the heatsink-ambient resistance. I was supposing to approximate the difference between the mean value of the heatsink (...approximation) and the ambient. In your way I cannot find anything useful, since I don't know the resistance between resistor-tempSensor-heatsink. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, it's for measuring the heatsink-ambient resistance.  The temp probe is measuring the heatsink temp at the point where the thermal load attaches.  The mean temp of the heatsink is not really relevant.  The idea of the arrangement in my answer is that you need to measure the highest-temp part of the heatsink, not some point that's halfway to cold.  By placing the sensor on the heatsink between two sources, it should get you that peak temp.  It doesn't measure the temp of the sources, i.e. the measurement excludes device-to-sink (grease) thermal resistance.

Comment: If you want to measure junction-to-anything resistance, you need the junction temperature.  That is a very difficult measurement to make in the general case, but you should be able to just take the datasheet value for junction-case for whatever device you have.